# Javascript: Calling different variables depending on variable

Tags: javascript, variables, discord.js

I'm trying to access different variables depending on user input. To simplify, let's say I have three variables, `x1 = "variable 1"`, `x2 = "variable2"` and `x3 = "variable3"`. I want to be able to call a different variable, depending on another variable, `y`. Let's say `y=2`, that means I want to get x2.

I tried something like `console.log(x[y])`, but that doesn't seem to work. I didn't find anything on this topic anywhere, so I don't know if it's possible or not, or if that's even how you would solve this problem.

For those who are interested, I'm trying to access different `Discord.RichEmbed()`s depending on the variable, and I don't think I can store those in an array. If that **is** somehow possible, please let me know.
If I forgot to explain something let me know and I'll add it or answer any questions you might have

Thanks in advance ^^

EDIT: It would also work if `y="x2"` and if I could then somehow get the contents of x2 that way.

Comment: Why do my comments keep getting deleted :|

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/5117127/90527)", "["Variable" variables in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/5187530/90527)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exhibiting a fundamental misunderstanding of JavaScript principles and my feeling is that you are essentially "hacking together" something for Discord.

I don't know if this will help you because there should probably be more context posted.

There are many ways to accomplish this.

You could create a method that has the source of variables and returns a reference to one of them based on a `y` variable passed as an argument.

```
const retrieveX = (y) => {
  const source = {
    x1: 'variable1',
    x2: 'variable2',
    x3: 'variable3',
  }
  return source[y]
}
retrieveX('x1')
```

Comment: Actually no, I'm just trying to make a fun Discord bot in my spare time ^^
Here's more context:
I'm trying to do "page switching" in an embed, which means I have pre-defined all possible "pages" of the embed as individual embeds. When the user reacts to the message, it's supposed to advance a page, so edit the message with another embed. I have a variable i storing the current page number and each embed is simple called "embed" with the number behind it. If I do it like sugessted, it gets the NAME of the embed, not the embed. So logging shows "embed2", not the contents of the embed.

Comment: Firgued out with the help of the code you provided, thanks a ton! ^^